# Read a dat. file with rows of just text in the middle in r

Tags: r, dataframe, readline, read.table

I have a series of very large datafiles which include my data plus additional info in the format of a line of text as comments. I want to read my data in a table and somehow include these comments as a text in just one column so I can go back and filter the data according to the comments. An example is provided here:

```
MTS793|BTW|ENU|1|0|.|/|:|1|0|0|A

Data Header:                                                Time:     0.051757813 s       12/12/2019     8:15:50 AM
Data Acquisition: Timed
Station Name: ArashFatigue.cfg
Test File Name: DistorsionFatigue.tst
Time      Actuator Force Actuator Displacement Top LVDT Bottom LVDT Web LVDT Flange LVDT
s         lbf       in        in        in        in        in
0.046875  216.01068 0.83545017 1.6925496 1.5586556 0.67528743 0.11848359


Data Header:                                                Time:     17.038574 s         12/12/2019 8:16:11 AM
Data Acquisition: Timed
Station Name: ArashFatigue.cfg
Test File Name: DistorsionFatigue.tst
Time      Actuator Force Actuator Displacement Top LVDT Bottom LVDT Web LVDT Flange LVDT
s         lbf       in        in        in        in        in
0.037597656 219.02016 0.83548528 1.6926224 1.5586556 0.67526972 0.11848105
0.045898438 218.44672 0.83548433 1.6925496 1.5585099 0.67528468 0.11848757
0.054199219 216.62195 0.8354823 1.6925496 1.5585828 0.675273 0.11848053
0.0625    217.15022 0.83549374 1.6926224 1.5586556 0.67527187 0.118481
0.070800781 219.7968 0.83547449 1.6925496 1.5585099 0.67526239 0.11848494
0.079101563 218.64467 0.83551377 1.6926224 1.5586556 0.67525345 0.11848123
```

If not, I want to at least get read of all the comments and just `rbind` all the numerical data in a table.

I am getting an error when trying to read the dat. file with `read.table` but `readLines` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

read the entire datafile as:

```
allLines <- readLines("data.dat")
```

Create a single column data.frame from the data:

```
allLines <- data.frame(a=as.character(allLines))
```

Filter-out the unwanted text:

```
allLines1 <- allLines %>% 
  filter(str_detect(a,"^[A-Z]"))
allLines2 <- allLines %>% 
  filter(str_detect(a,"^[a-z]"))
allLines3 <- rbind(allLines1,allLines2)
allLines_filter <- allLines[!(allLines$a %in% allLines3$a),]
allLines_filter <- data.frame(a=allLines_filter)
allLines_filter <- allLines_filter %>% 
  filter(str_detect(a,"^[0-9]"))
```

Split the data to a larger number of columns that you would anticipate to catch the spaces being treated as cell elements:

```
data <- str_split_fixed(allLines_filter$a , " ", 15)
```

Convert the matrix to a numerical data.frame:

```
data <- as.data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data <- map_df(data, as.numeric)
```

Shift the `NA` cells to the extra right columns and remove the extra columns (more than 7):

```
data[] <-  t(apply(data, 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))
stif <- data[,1:7]
```

Add the original header o the data to the final data.frame of numeric data

```
header <- c("Time", "Actuator.Force", "Actuator.Displacement", 
        "Top.LVDT", "Bottom.LVDT", "Web.LVDT", "Flange.LVDT")
colnames(stif) <- header
stif <- as.data.frame(sapply(stif, as.numeric))
```